# Preciso alocar novamente uma estrutura caso eu limpe apenas uma parte dela?

Tags: c, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Tenho uma `struct` que possui `nome` e `horário` para marcação de consultas.

```
              typedef Struct{
               char nome[20];
               char data[20];
              }Dados;
```

Faço a declaração:

```
           Dados *dados_cliente[quantidade];
```

Faço o alocação (sempre que eu  inicio uma nova marcação para não alocar tudo):

```
         dados_cliente[i]=malloc(sizeof(Dados));
```

Agora estou trabalhando para o usuário editar a marcação, eu poderia utilizar uma estrutura auxiliar mas preferi fazer dessa maneira:

```
        // SÓ VOU COLOCAR CASO ELE QUEIRA MUDAR O NOME PARA NÃO FICAR ENORME
        Case 1:
                free(dados_clientes[i]->nome);
                printf("DIGITE O NOVO NOME:\n);
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%[^\n]",dados_clientes[i]->nome);
```

Agora minha pergunta, quando utilizei o `free()` apenas no nome, eu preciso alocar novamente? Ou devo esquecer isso tudo e utilizar uma estrutura auxiliar mesmo, e/ou sugestões para resolver isso, caso possível.

Comment: Você está equivocado no que o `malloc` e `free` significam. Aconselho a começar a revisar por ai, aprendendo bem o que cada um faz e quais as implicações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C, quando há um ponteiro, este aponta para o primeiro *byte* da memória relacionada àquela variável. Quando há um vetor estático, o nome do vetor sem os colchetes com um índice também é tratado como um ponteiro, apontando para o primeiro *byte* de memória do vetor. Portanto, ao analisar a definição do tipo `Dados`

```
typedef struct{
    char nome[20];
    char data[20];
}Dados;
```

pode-se perceber que, em um ponteiro para `Dados`, como `dados_clientes[i]`, tanto `dados_clientes[i]` quanto `dados_clientes[i]->nome` apontam para o mesmo endereço da memória e, por isso não há falha de segmentação no comando `free(dados_clientes[i]->nome)`, mas toda a estrutura é liberada, pois é a mesma coisa de `free(dados_clientes[i])`.

Para solucionar o problema, basta eliminar o trecho `free(dados_clientes[i]->nome);`, pois o membro `nome` é estático e, portanto, não deve ser liberado dinamicamente. Outra possibilidade seria utilizar ponteiros para caracteres

```
typedef struct{
    char *nome;
    char *data;
}Dados;
```

Dessa forma, porém, seria necessário alocar memória dinamicamente para os membros `nome` e `data`

Comment: Muito obrigado, você entendeu a minha pergunta e conseguiu responder!! Agradecido.

Answer (score 3):

Tem uma série de problemas nesse código e até na pergunta, mas vou focar no que perguntou.

Este `free()` não faz o que está imaginando. Você só pode dar `free()` em algo que você deu `malloc()`, exatamente a mesma coisa, não pode inventar outra coisa para dar `free()`. Você poderia apenas não ter colocado na pergunta o `malloc()` no nome, mas duvido, e se o fez está bem errado.

Se o `nome` é um dado *inline* na estrutura não tem o que alocar fora dela, portanto não tem porque dar um `malloc()` para ele, o que eu acho que você não fez. O dado já está dentro da `struct`, se alocar espaço para ela, todo o espaço já está alocado, e se precisa liberar o espaço, tem que ser feito para toda `struct`.

Se deseja ter o nome com tamanho variável e fora da `struct` então coloque ali um ponteiro apenas e aí aloque o nome sob demanda, mas aí já é outro problema, e não temos informação suficiente para falar sobre isso, na verdade isto já é até especulação.

Comment: Sim eu utilizei a estrutura, quando eu faço um cadastramento os dados são jogados para a estrutura(não coloquei aqui para não ficar grande a pergunta), após eu cadastrar uma estrutura eu queria apenas caso o usuário queira fazer alterações, se ele quiser mudar o nome eu limpo o nome na estrutura correspondente e faço a alteração.

Comment: Se possível pontuar os erros que você diz ter no código pois não consigo ver, sempre utilizei estruturas dessa forma e funcionou(usava estruturas auxiliares) por isso estou tentando buscar outras formas de fazer isso mais rápido mas acho que não tem jeito.

Comment: É muita coisa e só com essas informações não vai adiantar muita coisa. E eu sempre postei aqui isto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQiXB.jpg. Você está aprendendo tudo errado porque acredita que funcionar quer dizer alguma coisa, e especialmente em C quer dizer nada útil. Funcionar é a pior coisa que pode acontecer para você.

Comment: acabei me equivocando nas palavras, peço perdão, sei que minha programação está no básico, acabei meu primeiro período de c no fim do ano passado, eu apenas aprendi essa forma para alocamento de estruturas de ponteiros, eu aloco uma estrutura inteira e coloco free nela inteiracaso eu queria excluir ela inteira também, para alterações eu sempre usei estrutura auxiliar, o usuário digita o que ele quer alterar e joga para a auxiliar que passa(substitui) para a estrutura original, mas estava tentando melhorar essa forma para não precisar de auxiliar.

Answer (score 0):

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char nome[20]; 
        char data[20];
    }   Dados;

    Dados *dados_cliente[quantidade];
```

O nome e a data em sua estrutura são `strings`, 20 bytes terminados por nulo. *"Limpar"* um campo desses pode ser apenas colocar um zero na primeira posição. Não precisa liberar memória e alocar de novo, e nem pode porque do modo como escreveu só pode alocar uma nova nova estrutura em `dados_cliente[i]`, onde todos são `Dados*`. Se por exemplo `nome` em `dados_cliente[i]` era *"vermelho"* quer dizer que tem um zero depois do *'o'*. E se vai trocar por *"azul"* basta gravar *'a' 'z' 'u' 'l' e '0'* a partir de `dados_cliente[i][0];`

`dados_cliente` é um vetor de ponteiros, de tamanho fixo. E os ponteiros é que são alvos possíveis de `malloc()` , `free()` e `realloc()`. E o que você pode *"liberar"* é o que você aloca, no caso os ponteiros, e um a um. Você pode iniciar todos com zero, o tal `NULL`, e depois liberar todos. `free()` em um ponteiro `NULL` é inofensivo, mas imagino que mantenha controle de quantos desses `quantidade` ponteiros estão em uso.

Se quer alocar um número variável dessas estruturas aí é diferente, e você declara

```
Dados ** cadastro;
```

por exemplo, e usa alguma lógica para controlar a alocação, como a que eu descrevi em um exemplo ontem aqui mesmo nesse [post onde tem um programa completo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469215/108192), Ou aloca um a um e usa uma lista ligada ou algum tipo de estrutura assim. Se for usar um bloco deles pode iterar como em `argv[i]` em `main()`, usando um vetor de ponteiros para estruturas, com o tamanho dado por `quantidade`, só que variável, como no caso do clássico par `argc/argv` de `main()`